# Installing software on Cent OS 5

Tags: centos, rpm

I've got a VPS with CentOS 5 where my company hosts a subversion repo. My problem is I want to install more software on there (like Trac) but I'm having a hard time.

Most tutorials tell me to use `yum` to install packages, but it has been disabled by the hosting company. They have also disabled compilers, so downloading source and installing that with `make` is no option either.

I got subversion running after using `rpm` to install loads of stuff, but now I want to install Trac I can't find the packages I need. It needs python, which needs other libraries, which all seem to require each other...

Am I missing something here? Is there a (easy) way to find and install rpm-packages and all their dependencies?

Comment: so your host disabled yum and compilers on VPS? Seems like a good reason to look for a new host!

Comment: I see my confusion is not that misplaced. I contacted the host earlier and they told me yum was disabled so I could not do stupid things, but I was free to install any software I'd like using rpm. Does that excluse malware or something? I'm thinking I should switch hosts...

Comment: yeah, that's crazy. You're much more likely to screw up the machine with RPM alone than with Yum. I think it's time to find a new host.

Comment: so why does the hosting company not want you to retrieve updates, including security updates...  my advice: move hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much RAM does your VPS have? Yum is known to puke itself trying to use under 200MB RAM. Seconding 3dinfluence, are you sure this is a VPS? Most VPS providers allow full root access to allow you to install almost any kind of software. A workaround may be to find an RPM for Yum and its dependencies. If you can get that installed you may be able to use Yum. But right now it sounds like you're on the fast track to RPM Hell :)

Comment: I did manage to install yum via RPM and it did puke. I guess that is why they made it so hard to get it. Went through RPM hell indeed, but got what I wanted in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called Yum :)  So why did the hosting company disable yum?  The only reason I can think is that they do not want you install software.  Maybe the proper course of action is to work with them to get trac installed on your VPS?

Comment: Yeah, I guess if they're gonna make my life miserable by excluding this stuff, I'm justified to make theirs miserable with support calls. Ill try it after the weekend. Thanks!

Comment: That or find another provider.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is called yum :).

Why would yum be disabled on a VPS especially when rpm isn't?  Sounds like a recipe to screw up a machine and end up in rpm dependency hell real quick.  Are you sure it's a VPS b/c that should be your virtual machine to do what you wish with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install yum throught rpm. If this doesn't work try to install CentOS in a local machine and put keepcache=1 in /etc/yum.conf. After "yum install trac", trac and all the dependencies are saved in /var/cache/yum . Upload the rpms to your server and install them with the rpm command.